# JavaScript updating last index class data

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have following issue. 
I have array of objects, and when I want to get one of the items and update data, it updates last data. 
for example:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  var c = new MyClass1(i);
  arr.push (c)
}
```

and the MyClass1

```
(function () {
var score = 0;
function MyClass1(id){
   this.id = id;
   this.x = 100;
  //some code. not important
}
var p = MyClass1.prototype;
 p.updateScore = function (s){
 score = s;
}
 window.MyClass1 = MyClass1;
}());
```

and function which returns one of these classes

```
var getMyClassesById = function(/* int */ id){
var size = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i<size; i++){
   if (id == arr[i].id){
      return arr [i];
   }
  }
}
```

Finally I'm calling function and want to update Score

```
getMyClassesById(1).updateScore (122);
```

it's updates last index item Score, and calls last item "updateScore" function... why?
but when i'm changing some other property its changes correctly for example "x". I can't understand is here something not right with prototypes?

Comment: `var getMyClassesById (/* int */ id){` <-- This should be: `var getMyClassesById = function (/* int */ id){`

Comment: Yes it's function I typed here wrong, now it's correct, but my problem not there. :)

Comment: Your problem is that MyClass1 is not going to be defined in your script, and will result in an undefined variable, that's the problem ;)

Comment: `score` isnt a propery of your class as `x` is

Comment: But in loop , i have defined (new MyClass1(i)), i'ts Ok, on the stage i See these classes but changes applied only on last added item :)

Comment: you want to say I should create it on "this"

Comment: If I actually run the code above, it doesn't even let me create a new instance of MyClass1, is this happening to me only?

Comment: yes I forgot to add window.MyClass1 = MyCLass1 sorry

Comment: I just think that you DON'T need at all an auto-invoking-anonymous-function for such a task. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/n0pgvz1u/

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `score` is not defined as a member of `MyClass` - it is only defined in the scope of your closure. Your code will work, but there will only be 1 "score" for all instances of `MyClass`.

If score is supposed to be part of `MyClass` then move it

```
function MyClass1(id){
   this.id = id;
   this.x = 100;
   this.score = 0
  //some code. not important
}
```

And update the method:

```
var p = MyClass1.prototype;
p.updateScore = function (s){
  this.score = s;
}
```

```js
(function () {

function MyClass1(id){
   this.id = id;
   this.x = 100;
    this.score = 0;
  //some code. not important
}
var p = MyClass1.prototype;
 p.updateScore = function (s){
 this.score = s;
}
 window.MyClass1 = MyClass1;
}());

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  var c = new MyClass1(i);
  arr.push (c)
}

var getMyClassesById = function(/* int */ id){
var size = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i<size; i++){
   if (id == arr[i].id){
      return arr [i];
   }
  }
}

getMyClassesById(1).updateScore (122);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: No it's not solved problem, still called last item (updateScore) Function, problem is here

Comment: @NarekHayrapetyan Take a look at the code snippet I added to this answer, run it and watch the console. Only the item with an id of `1` has its score updated.